# What is the proper way to assign to an array inside a C++ class?

Tags: c++, oop, matrix

I have this C++ class Matrix (see code snipet below).

In my randomize method, I set all the values of matr(matr is a 2x2 matrix).

When i call print_matrix it is duplicating elements (1,0) and (1,1) and printing them both twice, as well a not printing (0,0), or (0,1).

What am I doing incorrectly?

See the output below.

[image]

```
class Matrix {

public:


    int rows;
    int cols;
    double rnd;

    double* matr;

    Matrix(int a, int b) {

        printf(" vals %d %d \n", a, b);

        rows = a;
        cols = b;

        matr = new double[a, b];
        //this->print_matrix();
        //clear_matrix();
        //this->print_matrix();
        //this->randomize();
        //this->print_matrix();

    }



    double &at(int pos1, int pos2) {


        return matr[pos1, pos2];
    };

    void setPos(int pos1, int pos2, double value) {
        matr[pos1, pos2] = value;
    };

    void randomize() {

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                rnd = double(rand()) / double((RAND_MAX)+1.0);
                printf("Rand : %d, C: %d, Val: %f \n",r,c, rnd);
                this->setPos(r, c, rnd);
                //matr[r, c] = rnd;
                printf("New value R: %d C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, matr[r,c]);
                //rnd = 0;
            }
        }
    };

    void subtract_Scalar(double val) {
        double curr_Val = 0;
        double result = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                curr_Val = this->at(r, c);
                result = curr_Val - val;
                this->setPos(r, c, 0);
                this->setPos(r, c, (float)result);
                //this->setPos(r, c, 5);
                //printf("SS CV : %f, Re: %f  \n", curr_Val, result);
                curr_Val = 0;
                result = 0;
            }
        }
    };

    void print_matrix() {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                printf("PM R : %d, C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, matr[r,c]);
                //printf("%f", this->at(r, c));
            }
            //printf("\n");
        }
    }



    void clear_matrix() {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

                this->setPos(r, c, 0.0);
            }
        }
    }

    };
```

Comment: The syntax you used in `matr = new double[a, b]` is not how you declare or access a 2d array in C++.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: @Ayxan the comma operator can hide lots of errors

Comment: @Ayxan it does compile.  Also this is my first C++ program ever...

Comment: @MattWard Find a good and reliable source learn from there. C++ isn't a kind of language you should try to "just pickup"

Comment: @Ayxan At least `new double[a,b]` is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yes, but it really shouldn't be.

Answer (score 8):

<strike>Your program has undefined behavior because of the following line:</strike>

```
printf("PM R : %d, C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, matr[r,c]);
```

`matr[r,c]` does not access an element of the matrix. Due to the comma operator, it is simply `matr[c]`, which evaluates to a pointer. You are printing the pointer using `%f`. That's the undefined behavior part. You need to use `matr[r][c]` to access the element of the matrix.

```
printf("PM R : %d, C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, matr[r][c]);
```

Use of `matr[r, c]` is not right.

See [the documentation of the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) for further details.

---

#### Update

Thanks to the keen eyes of @PeteBecker, the problem is different than what I initially thought.

It turns out, `matr` is of type `double*`. Hence `matr[c]` evaluates to a double. Hence, the program does not have undefined behavior. It just accesses the `c`-the element of `matr` all the time regardless of the value of `r`.

The problem starts with:

```
matr = new double[a, b];
```

It needs to be

```
matr = new double[a * b];
```

Anywhere the element of the matrix is accessed using `matr[r, c]`, it needs to be `matr[r*cols + c]`.

In `at`, you need to use:

```
return matr[pos1 * cols + pos2];
```

In `setPos`, you need to use:

```
matr[pos1 * cols + pos2] = value;
```

In `randomize`, you need to use:

```
printf("New value R: %d C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, matr[r*cols + c]);
```

In `print_matrix`, you need to use:

```
printf("PM R : %d, C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, matr[r*cols + c]);
```

You can simplify the code for accessing the elements by providing an overload of `at` for `const` non-`const` objcts.

```
double& at(int r, int c) { return matr[r*cols + c]; }
double at(int r, int c) const { return matr[r*cols + c]; }
```

Then, `setPos` can be implemented as:

```
  void setPos(int pos1, int pos2, double value) {
     at(pos1, pos2) = value;
  };
```

The `printf` lines can be updated to:

```
printf("New value R: %d C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, at(r, c));
printf("PM R : %d, C: %d Val: %f \n", r, c, at(r, c));
```

Comment: How come `matr[r,c]` is evaluated as `matr[c]`? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: See the [documentation of the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: For future references, I am leaving this here: "In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins "

Comment: Um, `matr[c]` is a `double`. It wasn't intended to be, but that's consistent throughout. The type of `matr` is `double*` and it points at the first element of an array of `double`. All of the array operations end up treating it as such.

Comment: @PeteBecker, it's sad that the difference didn't get noticed until your keen eyes.

Comment: I had to stare at the code for quite a while. The problem is that we bring assumptions about how this kind of thing is implemented. This bug is truly insidious.